# Dragging a TButton from form to form

Tags: delphi, forms, button, drag-and-drop

I have a Delphi GUI app (with RAD studio 2010) and I want the user to be able to rearrange his workspace. I know how to make TButtons draggable around in the same form, but not how to make the user able to drag a button from one form to another form. When you click and attempt to drag a TButton, I don't think it treats it like a drag-and-drop operation. How do you get a TButton to be drag-and-drop capable across multiple forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set DragMode of the button to dmAutomatic, or manually call BeginDrag when a mouse down occurs on the button. Then use the OnDragOver + OnDragDrop events of the form you're going to drag to.

Answer (score 1):

Use the target form's OnDragDrop event to update the button's Parent property.

Comment: The OnDragDrop event is not triggered.

Comment: @John - Are you calling [`BeginDrag`](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/wwcstartingadragoperation_xml.html) (in `OnMouseDown`)?

Comment: Or setting the `DragMode` property to `dmAutomatic`.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know how to do it with Delphi's version of DragDrop, but it's perfect for the shell drag-drop with

```
IDataObject
```

and

```
IDropTarget
```

Except now you're forced to use Window's own API for drag-drop rather than Delphi's limited emulation.